# <i> not aligned in button Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a bit of testing on a project I'm working on and on Firefox, I have this button which looks like this:

[image]

instead of looking like this(in Chrome)

[image]

The code is straight forward:

```
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn_social_login">
                  <i class="logo fa fa-facebook"></i> 
                         Register with Facebook 
                 <i class="arrow fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>
```

With the left i float:left and the right i float:right. Page can be seen there http://kaboodle.io/sign_up . Can anyone tell me why this is happening on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Changing :

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Which is default on the .btn class in bootstrap

to:

```
white-space: normal;
```

fixed it.